How to do automated content publishing post deployment in XMCloud?
For DevOps (Automated Deployments), we currently have to manually perform content publishing after each deployment. We'd like to eliminate this manual step and automate the process post-deployment.
How can we automate content publishing in Sitecore XM Cloud using the Sitecore CLI or otherwise?
Additional Context:

We are running deployments through Azure DevOps to have more control over the process.
If this is available out-of-the-box (OOTB) with XM Deploy App-based deployments, please let me know, as this could be valuable for future projects.


You can leverage the xmcloud.build.json file to achieve this scenario.
Please add this section in the xmcloud.build.json
"publish": {
  "path": "/sitecore",
  "languages": ["en"],
  "itemIds": [],
  "targets": ["Edge"],
  "republish": true,
  "publishSubItems": true
}

Please refer to Sitecore documentation
https://doc.sitecore.com/xmc/en/developers/xm-cloud/the-xm-cloud-build-configuration.html#idp43994
Since /sitecore is a root item, it will republish the whole website.
In the logs, you could find the publishing log entry as follows:
[PublishOptions]: items:{11111111-1111-1111-1111-111111111111}, language:en, targets:Edge, database:experienceedge, mode:SingleItem, smart:False children:True, related:False


This will do full site republish? path and ItemIds are optional?

I have got confirmation from Sitecore Support and I have tried this and it works. Thanks a lot. And I have updated the JSON in your answer to working example to do Full Site Republish.

We can do automated content publishing as follows:
 // Login command
 dotnet sitecore login --client-id <<Client ID>> --client-secret <<Client Secret>> --allow-write true --client-credentials true
 
 // Connect environment command before running publish command
 dotnet sitecore cloud environment connect --environment-id <<Environment ID>>

 // Publish using environment name
 dotnet sitecore publish -n <<Environment Name>> --verbose

